# Values not displaying in Listbox from database using mvc5

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

in controller json method getting columnnames (Account,EmailTo,Subject,MessageContent) like this in ReportColumnsList ..but i need to pass these values in view page and display in listbox..
data is getting as [Object Object] and also displaying in listbox like this..
please give me solution regarding this..

Thanks & Regards

### in Controller part :-

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult GetColumnsByFavouriteReport(ReportsModel Model,string Columns)
{
    List<Report> ReportColumnsList = MCPAdminControllerPageObject.GetColumnsByReportName(Columns);
    return Json(ReportColumnsList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In view Part:-

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#FavouriteReports').change(function () {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '@Url.Action("GetColumnsByFavouriteReport", "MCPAdmin")',
              data: { Columns: $('#FavouriteReports').val() },
              datatype: "json",
              traditional: true,
              success: function (data) {

                  $('#SelectedFields').empty();
                  $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                      $('#SelectedFields').append('<option id="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>');
                  })

              }
          });
      });

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedFields, new SelectList(new[] { "" }), new { @class = "form-control editable" })
```

Comment: Did you get response from your ajax request ? any errors in console ? what you get in `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`?

Comment: Could you also please post rendered `html` for `@Html.ListBoxFor(`

Comment: Remove `data=JSON.stringify(data)`. The `$.each()` function parameters are the index and the item (not a key and val). What is the model your returning and what properties does it contain that you want to use for the value and text of each option

Comment: `JSON.stringify` returns JSON object, and `data` in AJAX `success` probably already contains JSON string - since `jQuery.each` uses index & value argument, then `stringify` method may totally unnecessary.

Comment: if i removed data=JSON.stringify(data) means getting [Object Object] like this in data

Comment: Show your model and the properties you want for the option value and text!

Comment: public List<string> SelectedFields { get; set; }

Comment: Your code shows your returning a collection of `Report` not `string`. And edit your question with the relevant details.

Comment: ListBoxFor - what you want single select dropdown or multi select dropdown ??

Comment: I have one ddl and one Listbox . based ddl selection i need to values in listbox.. this my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume Your model class Report

```
   public class Report {

    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public Name ReportName { get; set; }
   }
```

Inside your ajax method

```
   if(data!=null) {
    $('#SelectedFields').empty();
     var dd = null ;
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
       dd += "<option " + " value=" + val.ReportId + ">" + val.ReportName + "</option>";
        });
   //append to given id
    $('#SelectedFields').append(dd);
        }
```

I hope this will help your, bind your dropdown list

Comment: i need to display values in Listbox .. Not dropdown list